# Cannot change name to the App

Tags: android, xml

I've made an application and the `AndroidManifest.xml` has these attributes:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/flower"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.HomeActivity"/>
             <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.AboutActivity"/>
                  <activity android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.ContactActivity"/>
    </application>
```

If you look at [this](http://prntscr.com/1n09ve) picture you see the main page of my app. I want to change that `TabHostDemo` you see next to the fire flower with `MK7 VRs List`.

I googled and I found that if I want to change the title I have to edit some stuff in this way:

```
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:label="@string/app_name"
```

becomes...

```
android:label="@string/MK7 VRs List"
android:label="@string/MK7 VRs List"
```

If I do this I have an error that tells me "No resources found that matches the given name". Can you help me?

Comment: Open `res/values/strings.xml` and change the value of `app_name` in it. Then do a clean build.

Comment: or directly use `android:label="MK7 VRs List"`

Comment: Put it as answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `res/values/strings.xml` and change the value of `app_name` in it. Then do a clean build.

OR

or directly use `android:label="MK7 VRs List"`

Answer (score 2):

go to string/app_name and change it to what ever you want

```
<activity
            android:name="com.manish.tabdemo.TabHostActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```